# I am getting error in AS400 CL program when trying to declare field with type GRAPH

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, clp

I am getting error in CL program when trying to declare tablewith "Graphic field". Type "GRAPH"

`DCLF       FILE(MYTABLE)`

- CPD085C 40  Graphic field not allowed for variable &DESC.

Is there any way around this?

OS:  V7R4M0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CL doesn't handle graphic types, you can find workarounds in the message full help :

> Message . . . . :   Graphic field not allowed for variable &1.
> Cause . . . . . :   A graphic field was found, but ALWGRAPHIC(*NO) on
> the DCLF command was defaulted or specified.
> Recovery  . . . :   Specify ALWGRAPHIC(*YES) on the DCLF command, or
> specify a file or record format that does not contain graphic
> fields.

`ALWGRAPHIC(*YES)` will create a `CHAR(x)` that will be large enough to contain any binary value of `DESC`.
If you have to use `DESC` (compare, modify, ...), it would be better to use a language that knows graphic types.

Comment: I ended up copying data to QTEMP with SQL and reading it there.  Pretty kludgy.